# react-router-dom's Route do not work in my project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm in the very first step to create an project, but the react-router-dom's 'Route' just don't work. When i try to use it, just erase all other things in the screen.

My app.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import CoinPage from './Pages/CoinPage';
import Homepage from './Pages/Homepage';



function App() {
  return (


    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Route path="/" component={Homepage} />
        <Route path="/coins/:id" component={CoinPage} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>


  );
}

export default App;
```

My CoinPage.js:

```
import React from 'react'

const CoinPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        Coin Page
    </div>
  )
}

export default CoinPage
```

My Homepage.js:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Homepage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        Homepage
    </div>
  )
}

export default Homepage
```

My Header.js:

```
import React from 'react'



/*The header it self:*/
export const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        Header
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

When I remove `<Route path="/" component={Homepage}/>` and `<Route path="/coins/:id" component={CoinPage} />` the 'Header' component appears again

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap all your `Route` inside `Routes` Component

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
          <Routes>
           <Route path="/" component={Homepage} />
           <Route path="/coins/:id" component={CoinPage} />
         </Routes>
      </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

---

If you are using v6, then `component` has been replaced by `element` in Route

```
<Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
<Route path="/coins/:id" element={<CoinPage />} />
```

Comment: hang on, what are you trying to achieve? Homepage and CoinPage wont appear as you haven't called them , but added them as routes

Comment: That's weird the home page should show up at least, use `element={<Homepage/>}` instead... maybe that would work.

Comment: if you are using v6, the component has been replaced with element

Comment: I'm just fowling a YouTube tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QA6oTpMZp84), and in the video just work(you can see at 14:16).                     PS: use element don't change anything. And I'm sorry if I made any mistakes in writing, English isn't my first language.

Comment: The video has the whole source code at https://github.com/piyush-eon/react-crypto-tracker/tree/master/src. Have you tried running that?

Comment: Ok, i did what Tushar said in the last part of the answer, and now just Homepage show up, CoinPage don't appear.

Comment: Solved! I added each Route in a different Routes tag

Answer (score -1):

Solved!

I needed to change `component` to `element` and put each `Route` in a different `Routes` tag. Like that:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
        </Routes>
        
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/coins/:id" element={<Coinpage />} />
        </Routes>    
      </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: `Routes` component should wrap all of your `Route`s. You shouldn't have a `Routes` component for each `Route`...